# Include Multiple Classes In A Single Class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am brand new to C++ as of this weekend, and I'm struggling on a very core concept, as I'm unfamiliar with header files and the implementation files being separated like this.

I want to have a Class, let's call it "WorldCharacter".
And this Class, should contain lots of information about a character within a level.

However, for the sake of conciseness, I would like to split up this Class to include a number of other classes, like "WorldCharacterHealth", and "WorldCharacterSkills" etc.

What I would like to do then, is attach this WorldCharacter class to an Actor, as an ActorCompoent, and  it should display WorldCharacterHealth and WorldCharaacterSkills also.

However, after a day and a bit of trying to study ANY documentation to find this, I cannot find the answer to this solution.

**Header File**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "WorldCharacter.generated.h"


UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class GAME_API_NAME UWorldCharacter : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:  
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UWorldCharacter();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;


};
```

**CPP File**

```
#include "WorldCharacter.h"
// I thought perhaps I could include "WorldCharacterHealth.h" here (see below)

// Sets default values for this component's properties
UWorldCharacter::UWorldCharacter()
{
    // and then manipulate values like health or armour down here?
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // ...
}


// Called when the game starts
void UWorldCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    // ...

}


// Called every frame
void UWorldCharacter::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For the sake of argument, could `Health` and `Skills` be separated from `WorldCharacter`? Perhaps a `WorldCharacter` could be composed by a number of characteristics, like `Health` and a set of `Skill`s?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi Ted, apologies I wrote an answer to your question, but I think I may have misinterpreted it by the time I read my reply back. What do you mean, could be separated from WorldCharacter? My intention is that they ARE separated, but that WorldCharacter can be placed on an Actor, and I would see Health and Skills also. Does that make sense?

Comment: No apology needed - I asked for clarification about your setup and you gave it to me. Ok, `WorldCharacterHealth` looked like a class on its own which is why I reacted, but if you keep the details (than can be shared with NPC:s etc) separated, it looks like a good start. Edit: I need to read this again tomorrow - I noticed it's more to it than I can handle right now :-) What are these `Super::<method>`s all about?

Comment: Why can't you add those health and skill informations as members of `WorldCharacter` regardless what type they have? Can you clarify on you question because I cant seem to understand it?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Okay, I'm also a little confused - so say in C#, you can have Class, that has maybe int age = 32; WorldClassHealth worldClassHealth; How would you do that in C++?

Comment: @cmprogram It's very much alike in that respect - it's only your naming that confuses me right now.

Comment: like that: `struct WorldCharacter{ int age; WorldClassHealth worldClassHealth; }`. I guess you question is about how to "import" `WorldClassHealth` then? Put it in another header (and potentially cpp file). Then in you `WorldCharacter.h` include that file, e.g `#include "WorldClassHealth.h"`. If you need to access internal state, cpp also knows the concept of nested classes which can access private methods and members of the enclosing class. These are usually used for helper classes. E.g an internal `Node` class for a tree-based algo.

Comment: Maybe this clears things up: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ ?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I like the intention but directing people to `cplusplus.com` might set them off on the wrong track. That site is riddled with errors. `cppreference.com` is usually closer to the truth.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, except that many articles on cppreference.com are unsuited for inexperienced cpp programmers IMO. I did a quick read of the article and it seemed fine for me. Compare that one with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes to see where I am coming from.

Comment: Hey guys, I really appreciate you both taking the time to help me understand this, I understand it's an entry level question. When I try your answer Sebastian, I get the following error: 
Error Missing '*' in Expected a pointer type